# Extracting data from an object inside of another function without writing to JSON?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, youtube-dl

I'm working on writing a Discord bot with music functionality using discord.js and node, along with a handful of other packages like yt-search and ytdl-core.

The problem I'm trying to solve is related to the code below (newVar was just a placeholder while testing):

```
        let regex = /^https/i;
        let isUrl = regex.test(checkUrl);
        let songInfo;

        if (!isUrl) {
            yts(suffix, function (err, r) {
                if(err) console.error(err);
                const videos = r.videos;
                let data = JSON.stringify(videos[0])
                fs.writeFileSync('youtube.json', data)
            })

            let newVar = require('../youtube.json');
            let {url, title} = newVar;
            songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(newVar.url)

        } else {
            songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(args[1]);
        }


        const song = {
            title: songInfo.title,
            url: songInfo.video_url,
        };
```

What I'm trying to do,

- Is to check whether or not the 'suffix' is a URL, and if not, run suffix through the `yts() (yt-search)` function, and get the URL from the returned object.
- Then pass that url value through the `ytdl.getInfo()` function.
- It works as intended to an extent, but writing to the JSON is causing a problem in that it is returning the same URL even when a new search is completed, until the program is restarted,
- Then it will repeat the process with whatever value was stored in the JSON file when the program was executed. However, I get the results when I `console.log(videos[0].url)`, and the value changes with each query, but I have no way to pass that data outside of the `yts()` function without writing to the JSON first.

Any ideas?

I'm sorry if I'm not specific enough, or confused in my understanding, this is one of my first "complex" projects. It could also be that the issue exists elsewhere in the module, but from what I've done so far I think it's somewhere in the code shown above. Thanks!

Comment: where's the code to yts ? and you know what the youtube.json file is being required and processed before the yts function callback is triggered.

Comment: you should put that code from newVar inside the yts success callback as well.

Comment: @AneesIjaz thanks for the quick reply! yts is a node package I'm using, the syntax is `yts('query', function(err, r) {if (err) console.error(err) const videos = r.videos console.log(videos[0])})` passing through suffix instead of 'query' and it returns multiple objects, but I'm just trying to grab properties the first one `videos[0]`. The issue I'm running into when declaring any of the necessary variables inside yts is that they return as undefined when called elsewhere, which is why I thought maybe declaring the empty variables outside of the function then reassigning values would work.

Comment: I'm afraid this might just be a case of "I don't even know what I don't know," given my limited (but growing) understanding of programming. I'll keep tinkering though, and take any feedback/help I can get. So again, thank you for your reply @AneesIjaz!

Comment: well that may not be possible with current approach either you can create a promise and return the data in the promise or you will have to get along both the branches separately.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks again! @AneesIjaz

Comment: give me a minute I will give you a possible way.

Comment: where is the suffix variable defined ?

Comment: @AneesIjaz suffix is defined at the beginning of the `async execute(message)` function that wraps the entire module. I want the ability to pass through either a URL, or a string if checkUrl returns false (for keyword searches with yts, instead of direct links), so I have `const args = message.content.split(' ');` and `const suffix = args.slice(1).join(' ');` which is why songInfo appears in the `if...else` as both `songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(args[1])` and `songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(newVar.url)`. Hopefully that makes sense

Comment: the following code should work for you then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is something you can do to get it right.

```js
const getSongInfo = (url, suffix) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        let regex = /^https/i;
        let isUrl = regex.test(url);
        if (!isUrl) {
            // netween where is the suffix variable ?
            yts(suffix, async (err, r) => {
                if(err) reject(err);
                const videos = r.videos;
                let data = JSON.stringify(videos[0]);
                // still don't know why bother save it and access it again.
                fs.writeFileSync('youtube.json', data);
                let newVar = require('../youtube.json');
                resolve(await ytdl.getInfo(newVar.url));
            });
        } else {
            resolve(await ytdl.getInfo(args[1]));
        }
    });
}


// hope the outer function is async
let songInfo = await getSongInfo(checkUrl, suffix);

const song = {
    title: songInfo.title,
    url: songInfo.video_url,
};
```

Between make sure to check that suffix variable which is not in scope.